# 3.3 Geometry Nodes not preserving vertex groups?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I wanted to ask on here to make sure this isn't expected behavior that I did not expect.

I had a geometry nodes setup that did something very specific: it basically generates cage "shells" with options to adjust their values in a vertex group.

My setup worked flawlessly in blender 3.2, but once I updated to 3.3, the vertex groups seem to vanish into thin air? I'm very confused because the values are clearly present in the geometry nodes viewer.

I've uploaded a sample blend file. In 3.2, you should see this: [image]

However, in 3.3, you get this instead: [image]

Blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z4QGAfxEtdhN-oNKtSDjXCoGhCvhIRwl/view?usp=sharing

Is this a bug, or did something change that I'm unaware of? I read the update notes and I didn't see anything pertaining to this.

EDIT: I've isolated the problem down to this node setup. The behavior in 3.2 is different from 3.3. If you assign faces to a vertex group and use this node setup, the values will not appear in weight paint mode, nor will they be functional in simulations.: [image]

EDIT2: I managed to find this section in the manual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/attributes_reference.html#custom-attributes

And this bug report saying that the vertex groups were not supported in the long run: https://developer.blender.org/T95489

There is also this, which says that there is an "Attribute conversion" thing: https://developer.blender.org/T100186

Still haven't figured out what I need to do, but I'll update with another edit if I do before someone else answers this.

EDIT3: I'm pretty sure this is a bug. Vertex weight modifiers aren't affecting anything either.

EDIT4: If you apply the modifier, it will create an attribute that can be converted into a vertex group again. However, this requires applying the modifier, which is not always desirable.

EDIT5: I've submitted a bug report. It makes no sense to remove this functionality because of how insanely useful it was.

EDIT6: Not a bug. Regression for something that wasn't technically supported in the first place: https://developer.blender.org/T100908

Comment: same thing has happened to me with a rig that utilizes vertex groups generated by geometry nodes, i dont have an answer sorry, but leaving a comment to increase awareness

Comment: If you apply the Geometry Nodes Modifier, it will create a generic attribute that can be converted. I'm looking to find out if there's a way to do it without applying the modifier.